# No permission to load packages

Tags: r

I just joined a bank and with a lot of red tape I can’t lid packages in R  using install.package(). For me to do this I have to raise a request with IT long process. Is there a way to use packages without installing them in R Studio?

Fingers crossed

Comment: Do you have permission to save files anywhere on your computer?  You can use the `lib` argument  for `install.packages` to install it to a custom library location somewhere you do have permission to access, if that exists

Comment: Yes I do have permission to safe files somewhere on the desktop. How do I lib in install.package?

Comment: Okay I managed to ad lib to install.package() ran the code and it was fine but it looks like the I get the error HTTP status was ‘403 Forbidden’.